# Is it possible to use the Present Continuous for the Future in the 1st Conditional?

Tags: conditionals

As I understand grammar, these first two examples are correct when discussing with the 1st Conditional.

> If I get a pay rise, I will travel to the UK.

> If I get a pay rise, I am going to travel to the UK.

Is it possible for me to use the present continuous for the future in the conclusion/result?

> If I get a pay rise, I'm traveling to the UK.

Comment: Yes, the present progressive is fine in your sentence and with your intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any clause with future meaning --no matter what verb structure is used-- is fine. The structure of "first conditionals" only requires the main clause to have a future meaning. You can even use present simple:

> If this schedule is correct, the next train **arrives** in ten minutes.